# Is it possible to refer to the owner class that an object belongs to as an attribute?

Tags: python

I am not quite sure this is possible (or something similar) in python. I want to access a method (or another object) of a class from an object that is an attribute of such class.

Consider the following code:

```
class A():
  def __init__(self):
     self.b = B()
     self.c = C()
  def print_owner(self):
     print('owner')

class B():
  def __init__(self):
     pass
  def call_owner(self):
     self.owner().print_owner()
```

so that `b` as an object attribute of class `A`, can refer to a method or attribute of `A`?

Or similarly, is it possible that `b` can access `c`?

Comment: `self.owner` makes much more sense than `self.owner()` here.

Comment: Consider modifying the `WeakAttribute` example code from PEP 487. (If you're not using python 3.6, it's still possible with metaclasses.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible. You can pass a reference to A to B constructor:

```
...
    self.b = B(self)
...

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

So, B.a stores the reference to its owner A.

Comment: `self.owner` instead of `self.a` according to OP, but the concept is 100% sound.

Answer (score 8):

There can be many references to object `B()`, not only the one in instance of class `A`. So it's not possible as it is in your code. (Well you could try a hack, like finding all instances of class `A` in memory and find the one whose attribute `b` points to your B instance, but that's a really bad idea).

You should explicitly store in instance of `B` a reference to the owner.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options here. The better one is probably [@Sianur suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52109593/2988730). It's simple, effective, and explicit. Give that answer an upvote.

Another option is to have the owner force itself on its minions. `B` can do something like

```
def call_owner(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'owner'):
        self.owner().print_owner()
    else:
        print('I am free!')
```

Meanwhile, `A` would set the owner attribute to itself:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.b = B()
    self.c = C()
    self.b.owner = self.c.owner = self
```

In any case, if you want an object to have access to another object, store the reference into an accessible place. There's no magic here.